# How should I read mu4e's header symbols for threaded messages?

Tags: mu4e, email

So, I'm not very used to text-based/CLI mail client, so maybe this question may seem obvious to people who have used those for a while. I have in my `mu4e` inbox my messages from the Emacs help mailing list grouped by thread, like this (I added some letters as identifiers):

```
(A) Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf           
(B) o Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf     
(C) |LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf     
(D) | LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf    
(E) |  LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf   
(F) |>Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf     
(G) LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf      
(H)  o Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf    
(I)  LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf     
(J)   o Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf   
(K)   |>Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf   
(L)   |o Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf  
(M)   |LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf   
(N)   LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf    
(O)    LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf   
(P)     LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf  
(Q)      o Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf
(R)      |LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf
(S)      |>Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf
(T)      |>Re: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf
(U)      LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf 
(V)       LRe: Unicode characters for transcribing to pdf
```

Now, I know that the meaning of `o`, `L`, `|` and `|>` is to keep track of the replies, but I am not sure I understood what each one of them mean. **Can you please explain them?** For instance, what happens in the areas B-E, J-M and Q-T?